# How to merge data from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Guess I am in a complex situation. Heres the scene.
I have 3 tables in SQL Server.
Enrollment, Student, Course. (FYI, there are no foreign keys)
The table columns are
**Student** - StudentId, StudentName
**Course** - CourseId, CourseName
**Enrollment** - EnrollmentId, StudentId, CourseId, CourseResult

**Sample Data**
Student - s1, Sid
Course - c1, Science
Enrollment - 1, s1, c1, 80

I would want a SQL query that selects data like below

1, s1, Sid, c1, Science, 80

I did it hard way in the DAL layer with multiple calls to database. But would like to do it in one call, and in DB.

Any one for the rescue!

Comment: @Adam: Reddy does not understand that you can join tables in SQL to get the data in the requested format. The try was joining the data client side. It's not being stuck, it's not knowing that there's better alternatives.

Comment: @Paul: good thoughts. I see your point of view. To clarify mine a bit (not that it matters much since there are already several good answers): I suppose that I expected Reddy to have done more research and/or at least attempted a query of his/her own before asking a question and (perhaps) downvoting helpful answers.

Comment: @Adam: I've actually seen this scenario play out frequently during my career. Someone could be a programming wiz in a language but maybe never took a db class or maybe skipped the day that joins were covered. So then they attempt at joining the data in code and only when they realize how brutally difficult it is (if they realize it at all) might they go and look for a better solution. That was Reddy's experience here. A good, teachable moment.

Comment: @Adam: I tried nested queries but did not understand how to use current row data to call data in another table. I knew I was going in a wrong direction. So instead of spending time just on research which probably might not yield for some unknown time, thought if I could get community help parallelly!

Comment: @Reddy: I am glad to learn that you got the help you requested. For next time, please include the query you tried; however ugly it might be, because it helps folks better address specific conceptual misunderstandings you might be having. Cheers.

Comment: @Reddy: Per your last comment you should take a look at correlated subqueries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery (Subqueries would have worked but would also have been messy. It's always better to use joins to query your data than to use subqueries. Joins should also be more performant.)

Comment: FYI, there are two foriegn keys, these may not be identified in your database schema.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a join.

```
select enrollment.*, student.*, course.* from enrollment
   inner join Student on enrollment.studentId = student.studentId
   inner join Course on enrollment.courseId = course.courseId
```

Comment: +1 Nice, concise query and countering the overzealous downvote.

Comment: Probably the same reason I did. We did not arrange our SELECT clauses exactly as requested by the OP. I had a plain asterisk, as I always do when I start a query, you arranged your asterisk by table. Someone obviously really didn't like that. lol. As if Reddy couldn't figure out how to specify the columns...

Comment: Dont worry about the down votes... we know you gave the answer I needed!

Comment: I didn;t give you teh downvote, but I shoudl for encourageing teh use of select * especially in a query with joins. YOu are returning data you don't need (the joins fields for example are returned multiple times). Select * is a SQL antipattern and it's use should not be encouraged.

Comment: I was just trying to convey a solution.  specifying the individual fields is NOT germane. i dont think performance is the issue here

Answer (score 7):

There actually are foreign keys in your data model. They may not be marked as such in the db or you don't realize it. I also think it would become clearer if in your list you put the Enrollment table second, between Student and Course. Enrollment is the table that links a student to a course.

I think you just want an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) on the three tables like this:

```
SELECT e.EnrollmentId, s.StudentId, c.CourseId, c.CourseName, e.CourseResult
FROM Student AS s
JOIN Enrollment AS e ON s.StudentId = e.StudentId
JOIN Course AS c on e.CourseId = c.CourseId
```

Comment: @Reddy: Good. Do read up on table join. That wiki link in my answer is an OK start. Joins, inner and outer, are bread and butter in the art of SQL queries.

Comment: Sure there are foreign relations I could relate, but I did not, intentionally.  I got a long way to go in SQL. Thanks for the link BTW!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a few simple JOINs would do it...

```
select 
     e.EnrollmentId 
    ,s.StudentId
    ,s.StudentName
    ,c.CourseId
    ,c.CourseName
    ,e.CourseResult
from Enrollement e
  inner join Course c on e.CourseId = c.CourseId
  inner join Student s on e.StudentId = s.StudentId
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT e.EnrollmentId, s.StudentId, s.StudentName, c.CourseId, c.CourseName, e.CourseResult
FROM Student s JOIN
Enrollment e ON s.StudentId = e.StudentId JOIN
Course c ON e.CourseId = c.CourseId
```

Comment: Precise. But I got the answer already from above posts... Thanks anyway!